# How to replace a string in a list of strings with regex?

Tags: python, regex, list

```
my list = [
 '<instance id="line-nw8_059:8174:">',
 '  advanced micro devices inc sunnyvale calif and siemens ag of west germany '
 'said they agreed to jointly develop manufacture and market microchips for '
 'data communications and telecommunications with an emphasis on the '
 'integrated services digital network        the integrated services digital '
 'network or isdn is an international standard used to transmit voice data '
 'graphics and video images over telephone <head>line</head>   ',
 '<instance id="line-nw7_098:12684:">',
 '  in your may 21 story about the phone industry billing customers for '
 'unconnected calls i was surprised that you did not discuss whether such '
 'billing is appropriate    a caller who keeps a <head>line</head> open '
 'waiting for a connection uses communications switching and transmission '
 'equipment just as if a conversation were taking place  ',
 '<instance id="line-nw8_106:13309:">'
]
```

I have to replace all of the `<instance id="line-nw8_106:13309:">` (any variation) with a whitespace, along with added them all to their own list. I have figured out how to add them to their own list with regex like this:

```
instanceList =[]
    instanceMatch = '<instance id="([^"]*)"'
    for i in contentsTestSplit:
        matchy = re.match(instanceMatch,i)
        if matchy:
            instanceMatchy = matchy.group(0)
            instanceList.append(instanceMatchy)
    
    print("instance list: ",instanceList)
```

So this works, but I can't figure out how to replace all of them  with white spaces? I have attempted this along with using replace methods and it is not working, any help would be appreicated:

```
instanceList =[]
    instanceMatch = '<instance id="([^"]*)"'
    pat = re.compile(r'<instance id="([^"]*)"')
    for i in contentsTestSplit:
        matchy = re.match(instanceMatch,i)
        if matchy:
            instanceMatchy = matchy.group(0)
            instanceList.append(instanceMatchy)
            i = pat.sub("",i)
            
    
    print("instance list: ",instanceList)
```

Also have attempted this: but it doesn't replace, but does locate the occurrences accurately

```
for i in contentsTestSplit:
        if i.startswith("<instance id="):
            i.replace(i,"")
```

Comment: any occurance/variation of <instance id ="([^"]*)">

Comment: Is it literally coming into you split into strings like that?  If so, then couldn't you simply do `if i.startswith("<instance"):`?

Comment: That works at identifying where they are, but I still can't figure out how to replace it? I tried this:
```
for i in contentsTestSplit:
        if i.startswith("<instance id="):
            i.replace(i,"")
```

Comment: You can try: `for i,line in enumerate(contentsTestSplit:` / `if line.startswith("<instance"):` / `contentsTestSplit[i] = ""`.  It's often best in a case like this to copy the data to a new list with the changes, but this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex with substitution to replace all instances with a whitespace. You can then pass it a custom function to return the matches and append the results to your instances list.

```
def _sub(match):
    instanceList.append(match[0])
    return ''
    
instanceList =[]
instanceMatch = '<instance id="([^"]*)"'
for i in my_list:
    re.sub(instanceMatch, _sub, i)
```

I didn't know what you wanted to do with the processed data, but `re.sub(instanceMatch, _sub, i)` returns your text with the substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why id="([^"]*)" represent a string and if id="[^"]*" it represent nothing. what's
the using of ().